# Java Creating a vector with multiple ends

Tags: java, class, inheritance, vector, abstract-class

I want to create two types of vectors (as classes):

- The first type is a regular vector with two components (a start and an ending point).
- The second type is also a vector but instead of having one it has **two ending points** you can switch between.

My idea was to create an abstract superclass (e.g. `AbstractVector`) in which I define the common functions of the vectors:

```
abstract class AbstractVector {
    //Methods, e.g. length(), getter...
}
```

Then my two subclasses `Vector` and (e.g. ) `TriVector` extend the above class. The problem I'm facing is handling of the two ending points in the TriVector class.
I absolutely have no idea on how to do it or how to set up the abstract class correctly so I can have a normal vector and a vector with two endings between which I can switch (e.g. the `TriVector` class has a method `switch()` which switches between the two ending points).

I hope somebody can help me or propose a better solution.

Comment: Use a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (a **double ended** queue).

Comment: Rather than creating a new type of vector with a start and end, why don't you use the existing properties of a vector to calculate the end point? You can have your vector class have an optional origin. The x co-ordinate of the origin + the horizontal component of the vector gives you the end point's x co-ordinate, and similarly for the y component\

Comment: Thanks for your answers, a tried using a deque, but I aimed for only the TriVector having a deque but the Normal vector to having a normal point, if you understand me, but I can't set it right up.

Comment: If I understand correctly your `TriVector` should have `Point startPoint;`, `Point[] endPoint;` and `int activeEndPoint;`?

Comment: Yes you understood it

Comment: A vector is a multi-dimensional set of values. It's "one" point, not "two". Per vector math, you'd define your "starting point" vector `S` as your origin. Then the value of any "end point" vector `E` is just `E - S`, or subtracting the individual components of the two locations. This creates the vector from the location of S to E, which is the kind of vector you're actually looking to deal with (A vector describes displacement from the origin to begin with; you're just defining a different origin). In short with vectors: `E - 0 = E, E - S = E relative to S`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very rough sketch for a solution, only detailing the `getStart()` and `getEnd()` methods:

```
abstract class AbstractVector {
    protected Point startPoint;
    public Point getStart() {
        return startPoint;
    }
    public abstract Point getEnd();
    //Methods, e.g. length(), getter...
}

class Vector extends AbstractVector {
    protected Point endPoint;
    public Point getEnd() {
        return endPoint;
    }
}

class TriVector extends AbstractVector {
    protected Point[] endPoints = new Point[2];
    protected int activeEndPoint = 0;

    public Point getEnd() {
        return endPoints[activeEndPoint];
    }

    public void switchEnds() {
        activeEndPoint = 1 - activeEndPoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The only problem is, if you try to make something like this: AbstractVector v = new TriVector();  then you can't use the switchEnds() methods, probably I should precise this in my question.

Comment: @Ogu99 what should be the meaning of `AbstractVector v = new Vector(); v.switchEnds()`?